# Найти неизвестную цифру для математического выражения

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, функции

Дано математическое выражение, которое может содержать только "+", "-", "*", "=". В этом выражении пропущена цифра, вместо нее **"?"**. Искомая цифра не встречается в выражении, если таких цифр несколько, то вернуть наименьшую.Если нет подходящей цифры то вернуть **None**. 
Пример: на вход идет **" ?? * ??=302? "**,выходом будет **5**.
 Подскажите пожалуйста программу.

Answer (score 1):

Да что-то типа

```
def test(testStr,dig):
    return eval(testStr.replace('?',str(dig)).replace('=','=='))

val = '??*??=302?'

for i in range(0,9):
    if test(val,i):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Самое неэффективное, но зато не будешь долго времени убивать на нахождение алгоритма. Напиши парсер который будет преобразовать строку в выражение (либо 3 переменных, 2 для левой части равенства, 1 для результата правой *для описанного тобою случая)(переменные можешь хранить в массиве, а для вычисления левой части почитай за обратную польскую запись) и потом для этого парсера простым перебором подставь цифры